# Definition of piecewise $ C^1$-function

Tags: differential-geometry

I was reading the following: Let $ \gamma:[0,1] \to \mathbb{R}^3 $ be piecewise regular $ C^1 $-curve, that is there is a subdivision $ 0= t_0 < t_1 < \dots < t_n =1 $ such that $ \gamma $ restricted to any partial interval $(t_i,t_{t_i+1})$ is regular, that is $ \gamma'(t) \neq 0 $. So it could be $ \gamma'(t_i) = 0  $. Now let be $ s(t) := \int_0^t \vert \gamma'(\tau) \vert d\tau $. In this case $s  $ is strictly monotonic increasing and the inverse $ t $ of $s $ exists. Now $ t $ is strictly increasing since $ s $ is. But now the autor claims that $ t $ is piecewise of Class $ C^1 $. I don't understand why it should generally be piecewise of class $C^1 $, since the derivative of $ t  $ could explode at point where the curve is not regular.

Comment: But so what? It's still continuous on the open intervals.

Comment: But this would not correspond with the definition of pieceiwse $ C^1 $ I learned, like in https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Piecewise_Continuously_Differentiable_Function... This is why I am confused. So some authors talk about piecewise $ C^1 $ and mean that it is continously differentiable on $ (t_i,t_{i+1}) $ and don't require continuity and the boundary vakues?

Comment: Fair enough. To be honest, my understanding of a piecewise regular curve is that it's regular on each closed interval (so $\gamma’$ has different nonzero limits from the left and right. So what you're proposing will not be allowed to occur.

Comment: So is right to assume, that the author understands piecewise $ C^1 $ functions like I said?

Comment: No, I think the author thinks of a piecewise regular curve the way I just said. That's the standard situation in the differential geometry of curves. For example, to define exterior angles on a piecewise-regular curve, we need $\lim_{t\to t_j^{\pm}} \gamma'(t)$ to be nonzero vectors.